# Solving inverse tan for unknown variable

Tags: matlab

i try to solve to get variable from the inverse of tan. But  I got an error in Matlab.

Here my code:

```
syms x
solve(3*atan(-5*x) == -180, x)
```

The error I get is

```
 Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. > In solve at 179
```

My expected value of x is 0.3464. .

Comment: What error? 90% of the time, it will tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Also, are you sure you have your units right? It looks an awful lot like `-180` should be `-pi`. You will notice that `atan` has asymptotes around `+/- pi`, so `atan(blah)` can never be `-60` no matter how hard you try.

Comment: Mad Physicist is right; using pi instead of -180 gives 0.3464

Comment: I got an error 
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
> In solve at 179 

Thanks in advance, i tried 
solve(3*atan(-5*x) == -pi, x)
now, its ok.. 
many thanks..

Comment: Ohh wait,
I try to play with code, solve(atan(-5*x) == -pi, x) But I got an error again. .Explicit solution could not be found.

Comment: `pi` is a strictly numeric (floating-point) value. If you're using the symbolic Math toolbox sometimes it will be converted to the exact representation, but sometimes it won't depending on your equation. You should *always* use `sym('pi')` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially solving your equation gives `atan(-5*x) == -60`. This clearly has no solution since the range of `atan` is only defined from `-pi` to `pi`. It appears that you plugged degrees instead of radians in. The correct equation is `3*atan(-5*x) == -pi`.

Comment: I tried solve(3*atan(-5*x) == -pi, x) now, its ok.. many thanks..

Thanks for information . . .

Comment: The proper way to thank is to select my answer as the correct one by clicking the empty check mark. I am glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks I alredy clicked. 

Ohh wait, I try to play with code,
solve(atan(-5*x) == -pi, x)
But I got an error again. .Explicit solution could not be found.

Comment: Because atan is asymptotic to -pi, meaning x is -infinity for atan(x) = -pi. Try .... = -pi + 0.0000001 or something like that.

Comment: Hi, i try different question to play with code again.
atan(-10*x)+atan(-5*x) -x= -pi
Firstly i try to run from wolframalpha.com to solve, and I got the right ansewr. Here the link:
[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan%28-10*x%29%2Batan%28-5*x%29+-x%3D+-pi)

But, when I to used in matlab, the answer only variable x. Here's the code:

>> 'syms x'
>> 'solve(atan(-10*x)+atan(-5*x) -x == -pi, x)'

therefore, how to code for that variable in matlab?